# Passing form value from first page to 4th page

Tags: php

1. My first file is signup.php and it has form in it. I need to pass the form value to the 4th page i.e createAccount.php.

   2. After signup.php i have a userAgreement.php(2nd file) file that is linked with creaditCardInfo.php(3rd file) file. In the end, I have createAccount.php file.
   3. I need help. I know i can store form values in $_session but its not working.
   4. Can you please help me to figure out where is the mistake?
   5. below are my 4 files.

      ```
      <?php
      include 'preCode.php';
      include 'header.php';
      echo '<body><div class="standardLayout">';
      echo '<h2>Account Information</h2>';
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="userAgreement.php">
      <table>
      <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
      <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fName"></td</tr>                   
      <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create Account"></td></tr>
        </table>
         </form>
       <?php
       echo'</div>';
       include 'footer.html';
        ?>
      ```

      userAgreement.php(page 2)

      ```
         <?php
         include 'preCode.php';
         include 'header.php';
         echo '<body><div class="standardLayout">';
         include 'systemMenu.php';
           $_SESSION['email'] = secure_input($_POST['email']);
           $_SESSION['fName'] = secure_input($_POST['fName']);
           ?>
      ```

      creditCardInfo.php(page 3)

      ```
           <?php
              include 'preCode.php';
              include 'header.php';
               echo '<body><div class="standardLayout">';
               include 'systemMenu.php';
               $_SESSION['email'] = secure_input($_POST['email']);
               $_SESSION['fName'] = secure_input($_POST['fName']);
              ?>
      ```

      createAccount.php(page 4)

      ```
          <?php
           include 'preCode.php';
           include 'header.php';
           echo '<div class="standardLayout">';
           include 'systemMenu.php';
           $_SESSION['fName'] = secure_input($_POST['fName']);
           $_SESSION['email'] = secure_input($_POST['email']);
           $email = $_SESSION['email'];
           echo $email;
           $_SESSION['fromLogin'] = false;
           $user = new user();
           $user->fName = secure_input($_POST['fName']);
           $user->email = secure_input($_POST['email']);
           $query = "INSERT INTO Users (fName, email)VALUES ('" . $user->fName . "', '" . $user->email . "');
           echo '<h2>User Information</h2>
          <div class="left">
         <form method="post" action="editUser.php">
          // I want to display session values here in this form. But its not printing anything except the field names(Name and email).
        <i>Name:</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '$user->fName . '<br>
        <i>Address:</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'$user->address .'<br>
         <input type="submit" value="Edit Information"></form>';
      ```

Comment: Why do you keep assigning the session variables in each page? Just assign them in the first page, and use them in all the rest.

Comment: I can see no session_start() at the top of each page - is this within one of the included scripts or have you omitted it altogether?

Comment: session_start() is included in a header.php file

Comment: Do any of the pages display session vars if you were to include a print_r( $_SESSION )? The first page will not have any session variables set - you would only begin setting the vars after the initial POST of the form

Comment: Do I need to store values of first page into session too?

Comment: @RamRaider....  its giving me this value if i include print_r($_SESSION);Array ( [fromLogin] => [user] => N; [email] => [fname] => [lname] => [fName] => [lName] => [fromEditPage] => 1 [address] => [zip] => [phone] => [password] => )

Comment: session should be started at the very beginning of the code with no white space before starting of <?php tag. I sow that you have include 'preCode.php' before header.php file. Does the preCode.php file contains any white space?

Answer (score 1):

The final page ( createAccount.php ) appears to be where the problems lie. You assign values to session vars based on a form submission, but judging by the code there is no form submission to that page. Rather than assign these vars erronously, simply use the stored session variables and don't reassign with effectively null values. In fact, the same is true on page 3 too - there does not appear to be a form that posts to page 3 so once again you overwrite the session vars with null values. Of course, there might be a form within the included file but if that is the case why is there another pair of fields 'email' and 'fName'??

```
creditCardInfo.php(page 3)
--------------------------
 <?php
    include 'preCode.php';
    include 'header.php';
    echo '<body><div class="standardLayout">';
    include 'systemMenu.php';
 ?>

 createAccount.php(page 4)
 -------------------------
<?php
     include 'preCode.php';
     include 'header.php';
     echo '<div class="standardLayout">';
     include 'systemMenu.php';

     $email = $_SESSION['email'];
     $_SESSION['fromLogin'] = false;

     echo $email;

     $user = new user();
     $user->fName = $_SESSION['fName'];
     $user->email = $_SESSION['email'];
     $query = "INSERT INTO Users (fName, email)VALUES ('" . $user->fName . "', '" . $user->email . "');

     echo '
        <h2>User Information</h2>
        <div class="left">
        <form method="post" action="editUser.php">
            <i>Name:</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; '.$user->fName . '<br>
            <i>Address:</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$user->address .'<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Edit Information">
        </form>';
?>
```

Comment: there is no form in included files.

Comment: so, look at the code! You are trying to assign POST variables to a session var when there is no form POSTing data to those pages. Assign these variables to session vars on page 2 ( userAgreement.php ) and then refer to the session var only

Comment: Is that correct?  $_SESSION['email'] = secure_input($_POST['email']);
                  $_SESSION['fName'] = secure_input($_POST['fName']);
                  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                  $fName = $_SESSION['fName'];

Comment: There is however the possibility that your code could be exploited using sql injection however so you ought to look at PDO or mysqli!

Comment: Hi! i need to make changes in my code again.      1. My first file is signup.php. It has a signup form. I am storing values of this form in a session.
2. Second is userAgreement.php(include an agreement).
3. Third file is creditCardInfo.php. It also include a form and a checkbox. If the values of first file and third file is same check this box.
4. My problem is this, i dont know how can i copy values of  signup.php file to creditCardInfo.php if a person checks a checkbox on creditcardInfo.php file.

Comment: I am using this function in creditCardInfo.php page. But its not working.function         FillBilling(f) {
                                     if(f.billingtoo.checked == true) {
                                      f.billingFname.value = $fName;
                                      f.billingLname.value = f.$lName;
                                     f.billingAddress.value = f.$address;
                      
                                      f.billingZip.value = f.$zip;
                                      f.billingPhone.value = f.$phone;
                      
                    }
}